# Image OutOfMemoryError in Asynctask

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I tried to invoke images from url async method. It produces Out of memory error on do in background. My code is below

Code:

```
class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder1, Void, ViewHolder1> {

    @Override
    protected ViewHolder1 doInBackground(ViewHolder1... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // load image directly
        ViewHolder1 viewHolder = params[0];
        try {
            String url = viewHolder.imageURL.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL imageURL = new URL(url);
            Log.v("Image Url", viewHolder.imageURL);
            viewHolder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("error", "Downloading Image Failed");
            viewHolder.bitmap = null;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder1 result) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Result bitmap", String.valueOf(result.bitmap));
        if (result.bitmap == null) {
            result.frndthumb_image
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_image);
        } else {
            result.frndthumb_image.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.arrichion.userservices.ChallengesAdapter$DownloadAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChallengesAdapter.java:133)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.arrichion.userservices.ChallengesAdapter$DownloadAsyncTask.doInBackground(ChallengesAdapter.java:1)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-13 13:40:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Aquery to download images.just download the jarfile from below link

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query.0.26.7.jar

and call this using

```
AQuery _aq = new AQuery(youractivity context);
//fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
aq.id(R.id.Your imageview object).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```